# What does the python runtime environment mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I was reading this [article about the sys module in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sys-module/#:%7E:text=The%20sys%20module%20in%20Python,interact%20strongly%20with%20the%20interpreter)

And I came across this line:

> The sys module in Python provides various functions and variables that are used to manipulate different parts of the Python runtime environment. It allows operating on the interpreter as it provides access to the variables and functions that interact strongly with the interpreter.

Can someone explain what this means? I don't get it

Comment: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5466/runtime-environment-rte

Answer (score 0):

The Python runtime environment is the program that runs your python-scripts.
This program is called 'python' or 'python.exe'

Making a python-program means: Making a script (eg: MyScript.py) that can be fed in the python.exe program.

from the command prompt:   python.exe MyScript.py

The sys module can be used in debugging (large) python-scripts.

Good Luck!

Comment: so it is not worth learning the sys module as an intermediary python student?

Comment: That's correct!